# How to export spring boot metrics as single json

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-boot-actuator, metricbeat

Spring boot actuator's /metrics returns list of metrics names

```
{
"names": [
"jvm.gc.pause",
"tomcat.global.received",
"jvm.memory.used",
...
]
}
```

I want to configure the metrics aggregation via elastic search metric beat. I use elastic search auto discovery and http module

```
 metricbeat.autodiscover:
      providers:
        - type: kubernetes
          host: ${HOSTNAME}
          templates:
            - condition.equals:
                kubernetes.labels.app: employee-rewards
              config:
                - module: http
                  metricsets: json
                  period: 10s
                  hosts: ["${data.host}:8080"]
                  namespace: "app_metrics"
                  path: /actuator/metrics/jvm.gc.pause
                  method: "GET"
                - module: http
                  metricsets: json
                  period: 10s
                  hosts: ["${data.host}:8080"]
                  namespace: "app_metrics"
                  path: /actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.used
                  method: "GET"
```

Problem with approach is when ever microservices team add a new metric, i need to configure metric beat to include the added metric.

Instead is there any way to get all the metrics values in a single json?

```
{
          "@timestamp": "2018-08-14T20:16:02.339Z",
          "tomcat_global_received_count": 0,
          "tomcat_global_request_max_value": 0.3569999933242798,
          "tomcat_sessions_active_current_value": 0,
          "tomcat_sessions_active_max_value": 0,
          "tomcat_sessions_expired_count": 0,
          "tomcat_sessions_alive_max_value": 0,
          "jvm_memory_committed_value": 854982656,
          "jvm_gc_pause_max": 0,
          "jvm_gc_pause_count": 4,
          "jvm_memory_used_value": 429412576,
          "tomcat_global_request_count": 106,
          "host": {
            "name": "webapp003.my.network.example.com"
          },
          "jvm_threads_peak_value": 64,
          "jvm_memory_max_value": 4518313984
}
```

I know that actuator supports a push mechanism to push the metrics directly to elastic search. But i cannot use this because i want additional details about kubernetes environment as part of the metrics which is supported by metricsbeat.